# How to debug cython program in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, python, debugging, cython, pdb

I want to debug Cython code in terms of Cython namespace, I don't want to dive inside derived C code. I use Windows 7, Python 2.7 64 bit, PyCharm, MS Visual Studio 2008. Which debugger options do I have? (I'm especially interested in non-console visual debugging). Where can I find relevant installers compatible with my environment?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using the same configuration as your and when you run `cython file.pyx` you already get a pretty good debug info in case something is wrong. The only gotcha is when you have some buffer array like `cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a`, and `a` is not used in the code... this is hard to find...

Comment: additionally, you can run with `import pyximport; pyximport.install()` in your Python file calling the Cython module in order to do fast try-outs...

Comment: you may be interested in visualgdb or wingdb using cygdb